# How do I determine if I should use a license for my writing?

Tags: licensing

I have been writing a blog for a number of years, and it occurred to me that I never released any of my writing under a license.

My question is, how do I determine whether or not I should use a license with my work?

Why would this be better than any copyright?

Comment: It's all up to you, and should vary on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Another thing: Writing is considered to be a creative work, so Creative Commons would work best here

Answer (score 6):

The only reason you would need to associate a licence with your blog is if you want others to be able to take and use your material on other sites.
Without a licence, it falls under the copyright laws of one of:

- The country in which you reside
- The country where the server you publish on resides
- The home country of the company that **owns** that server
- The country where the person who takes your content resides
- Somewhere else

Resolving that needs the services of one or more lawyers, but most countries are signatories to the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention)

Licenses are about about relaxing your copyright protection in a way that you control.

The other thing to consider, unless you publish on your own server, is that the blog service you use may stipulate a licence in its terms and conditions.